# How can I change divIcon className on click?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, marker

I have a leaflet map with several markers on it. On click on a marker this one should get highlighted. I use `divIcons` and want to change the whole icon or the className of it, both would work for me. At the moment i'm just changing the class of the created `div` in the html tree to highlight it. This works great, but i ue  a marker clusterer. Therefore the divs get created and dumped on and on again and my highlight class dissapears at each clustering.

Markers:

```
var markerIcon = L.divIcon({
   className: 'marker--default',
   html: "15",
   iconAnchor: [20, 20]
});
var markerIconActive = L.divIcon({
    className: 'marker--state--active',
    html: "15",
    iconAnchor: [20, 20]
});
```

Integration of Marker:

```
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({});

markers.addLayer(L.marker([50.919523, 6.940621], {icon: markerIcon})).on('click', onClick);

map.addLayer(markers);
```

Clickevent:

```
function onClick(e) {
   e.target.setIcon(markerIconActive);
}
```

Note:
It doesn't work. I get the error "e.target.setIcon is not a function". After reading the documentary it seems that there is no setIcon method for divIcons. As said it would be working for me too if just the className get changed, but i don't know how to change this one.

Documentation:

https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#divicon

Comment: What is `markers`? You're adding the event handler to `markers` instead of to the individual marker.

Comment: ah, thank you, i forgot a line of code ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to access the functions / properties via `e.target.<function>` use `e.<function>` or `this.<function>`:

```
function onClick(e) {
   e.setIcon(markerIconActive);
}
```

alternatively, you can access it through `e.layer`:

```
function onClick(e) {
   let marker = e.layer;

   marker.setIcon(markerIconActive);
}
```

**Reading Material**

[Is there a way to click on any map *marker* and retrieve the marker's lat/lng (or array index)?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/leaflet-js/RDTCHuLvMdw)

Comment: The first variant just returns an error ("e.setIcon is not a function") but the second one does the trick, thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change the class of your div, the native function is [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). You can use it along-side with `stopPropagation` to prevent the first bug you pointed out. like so

```
function onClick(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.target.classList.toggle('newclass');
}
```

You also can use `replace` method instead of toggle if you want a "switch"

```
function onClick(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.target.classList.replace('oldclass','newclass');
}
```

Don't forget to pass the event buble through the onClick function when you call it `$.on('click', onClick(e))`

```
markers.addLayer(L.marker([50.919523, 6.940621], {icon: markerIcon})).on('click', onClick(e));
```

Comment: I just get an error that e.stopPropagation is not a function.

Comment: yes, because you never passed the event through your function, see my edit